# how to get the line number from the list and write it to a vector

Tags: r, list

I have a list in which the rows from the data frame are stored.

```
kl <- list(structure(list(GROUP = "1", col6 = NA_character_, col7 = NA_character_, 
    dif = NA_character_, p.value = NA_character_), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(GROUP = "2", col6 = NA_character_, col7 = NA_character_, 
        dif = NA_character_, p.value = NA_character_), row.names = 3L, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(GROUP = "3", col6 = NA_character_, col7 = NA_character_, 
        dif = NA_character_, p.value = NA_character_), row.names = 5L, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(GROUP = "4", col6 = NA_character_, col7 = NA_character_, 
        dif = NA_character_, p.value = NA_character_), row.names = 7L, class = "data.frame"))
```

how to get the line number from the list and write it to a vector

```
kl.vec <- c(1,3,5,7)
```

Comment: do you mean something like `sapply(kl, \(x) as.numeric(row.names(x)))` ?

Comment: Yes, your option suited me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an little tweak approach using `sapply` (like @SBMVNO):

```
as.numeric(sapply(kl, rownames))
```

output:

```
[1] 1 3 5 7
```

Answer (score 2):

Test data as below:

```
kl <- list(structure(list(GROUP = "1",  row.names = 1, class = "data.frame")), 
           structure(list(GROUP = "2",  row.names = 3, class = "data.frame")), 
           structure(list(GROUP = "3",  row.names = 5, class = "data.frame")), 
           structure(list(GROUP = "4",  row.names = 7, class = "data.frame")))
```

then we can do

```
sapply(c(1:length(kl)), FUN=function(x) kl[[x]]$row.names)
```

it returns

```
1 3 5 7
```

As commented by @Darren Tsai , I should consider it as a list of dataframe, instead of thinking something wrong with the question's data as there are many NAs. The modified answer would be

```
sapply(1:length(kl) , FUN= function(x) rownames(kl[[x]]))
```

Surely, @TarJae 's answer is concise.

Comment: The original data returned lots of NA. I simply *guessed* the data to show how to obtain 1, 3, 5 ,7.

Comment: I don't mean the `NA`. I mean that the code you reproduce the data results in a wrong structure. Could you re-run your code `kl <- list(...)` and check the structure? It's a list of list, instead of a list of data.frame.

Comment: It is a list of list. As what I said, I guessed what kl might be. Thus, I included my version of kl as what I guessed. My intent was to show "sapply" might be an answer.

Comment: You have specified `class = "data.frame"` in `structure()`. But it returns a `list` instead of a `data.frame`. It's contradictory, right? The OP's data is 100% a list of `data.frame`s. It's impossible to extract row names of a data.frame by `data$row.names`, except that the data.frame has a column named `"row.names"`.

Comment: The syntax you produce the data should be: `structure(list(GROUP = "1"),  row.names = "1", class = "data.frame")`. It looks like your code but returns a `data.frame`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe we could rbind and get the `rownames` (assuming they are different)

```
as.numeric(row.names(do.call(rbind, kl)))
[1] 1 3 5 7
```